# Path of a picture in a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using a simple `GridView` in Android to display pictures from the photo library. My code can get the picture path:

For example : storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161205_101211.jpg

My `GridView` adapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.face, R.drawable.face2,
            R.drawable.face3, R.drawable.face4,
            R.drawable.face5, R.drawable.face6,
            R.drawable.face7, R.drawable.face8
    };
}
```

I would like to use the picture path in the `mThumbIds` instead of using the picture in the assets folder to display the pictures but I don't really know how to do that. Should I convert the picture path into a `Bitmap`?

Comment: Use one of [the seemingly-infinite number of image loading libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as Picasso. These can load your images into the `ImageView` asynchronously, so the act of loading the images does not tie up the main application thread and freeze your UI.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
try {
    // get input stream put name here
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    return;
```